# PDO reports failed execution but error code suggests otherwise

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm just using PDO to insert customers into my table but it has been overcomplicated by something which is unexplainable by myself or other research. 
It gives the error code: 00000 (which means that is a success, apparently) but no data was actually inserted into the database and the error is only supposed to be outputted if the query was a failure, but the error is.. success?

```
$insertUser = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO customer (Surname, Forename, AddressRow1, AddressRow2, AddressRow3, AddressRow4, PostCode, Telephone, mobileNumber, Email, assignedGarage)
                            VALUES (:surname, :forename, :addressrow1, :addressrow2, :addressrow3, :addressrow4, :postcode, :telephone, :mobilenumber, :email, :assignedgarage)");
$insertUser->bindParam(':surname', $_POST['surname']);
$insertUser->bindParam(':forename', $_POST['forename']);
$insertUser->bindParam(':addressrow1', $_POST['addressrow1']);
$insertUser->bindParam(':addressrow2', $_POST['addressrow2']);
$insertUser->bindParam(':addressrow3', $_POST['addressrow3']);
$insertUser->bindParam(':addressrow4', $_POST['addressrow4']);
$insertUser->bindParam(':postcode', $_POST['postcode']);
$insertUser->bindParam(':telephone', $_POST['telephone']);
$insertUser->bindParam(':mobilenumber', $_POST['mobilenumber']);
$insertUser->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$insertUser->bindParam(':assignedgarage', $_SESSION['garageId']);
if(!$insertUser->execute()) {
    $err[] = $database->errorCode();
}
elseif ($insertUser->rowCount() == 1) {
    $id =  $database->lastInsertId();
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
<!--
window.location = \"updateUser.php?id=$id\"
//-->
</script>";
}
if(count($err)) {
        echo "<p style=\"color:red;\">The following errors were detected:</p><br/>";
        foreach ($err as $key => $error) {
            echo "<p style=\"color:red;\">$error</p><br/>";
        }
    }
```

I first started without defining all the columns I wanted to insert into but that didn't work so I predefined them. 
[image: A rudimentary customer table design, I have my reasons for having the telephone/mobile numbers as varchars.]

My table in its early, rudimentary stages. I have my reasons for choosing varchars for mobile/telephone numbers.

Comment: Try `$insertUser->errorCode()`

Comment: Check for an error from `$database->prepare()`.

Comment: With $insertUser->errroCoder() I get: HY000, is that a connection error? As all my other queries run off the same function to initialise the database connection and are in a similar format.

Comment: I *highly* recommend [setting](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) PDO to throw exceptions on error. It makes the entire error handling mechanism a) a lot easier to see when you got an error during development, because it blows up in your face and screams at you when something goes wrong, and b) a lot cleaner in production, because you can simply wrap an entire exchange, prepare exec et al, in a single try catch, and know that you only have to handle errors in a single location in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarising, you have this:

```
$insertUser = $database->prepare(...);
if(!$insertUser->execute()) {
    $err[] = $database->errorCode();
             ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

So you're calling [PDO::errorCode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php) rather than [PDOStatement::errorCode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php). As the manual explains:

> PDO::errorCode() only retrieves error codes for operations performed
> directly on the database handle. If you create a PDOStatement object
> through PDO::prepare() or PDO::query() and invoke an error on the
> statement handle, PDO::errorCode() will not reflect that error. You
> must call PDOStatement::errorCode() to return the error code for an
> operation performed on a particular statement handle.

Depending on your needs and current code, you might also be interested in [PDOStatement::errorInfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php), which provides error details in friendly format. And, of course, you can also instruct PDO to throw exceptions and get rid of manual error checking.

Comment: I've moved my code to try, catch errors and it's much more informative, it turns out my id doesn't have a default value and it gave me "General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value" much better than errorcodes! Many thanks for everyone elses input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead and tell me what you find:

```
try{
   $database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)

   $insertUser = $database->perepare("INSERT INTO customer (Surname, Forename, AddressRow1, AddressRow2, AddressRow3, AddressRow4, PostCode, Telephone, mobileNumber, Email, assignedGarage) VALUES (:surname, :forename, :addressrow1, :addressrow2, :addressrow3, :addressrow4, :postcode, :telephone, :mobilenumber, :email, :assignedgarage)");

   $insertUser->execute(array(':surname'=>$_POST['surname'], ':forename'=>$_POST['forename'], ':addressrow1'=>$_POST['addressrow1'], ':addressrow2'=>$_POST['addressrow2'], ':addressrow3'=>$_POST['addressrow3'], ':addressrow4'=>$_POST['addressrow4'], ':postcode'=>$_POST['postcode'], ':telephone'=>$_POST['telephone'], ':mobilenumber'=>$_POST['mobilenumber'], ':email'=>$_POST['email'], ':assignedgarage'=>$_SESSION['garageId']));

    if ($insertUser->rowCount() == 1) {
    $id =  $database->lastInsertId();
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
<!--
window.location = \"updateUser.php?id=$id\"
//-->
</script>";} else{
   //sum'n sum'n
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo 'Error occured'.$e-getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `$database->errorCode();` will not work for operations not directly performed on DB handle as in your case (you used `PDO->prepare()`). In your case this error code is reffering to last successful query not the one you are trying to execute, hence the 0000 error code.

You most likely have an error in your params array (values that are passed from `$_POST`). Also when using `bindParams` method you should specify the type of variable that is expected by database.

Comment: The `$data_type` parameter is optional and defaults to `PDO::PARAM_STR`, which is pretty safe in MySQL context.